# How to download the latest version of the project from Github to a local disk?

Tags: c#, github, octokit.net

I usually download a project by reference [see Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9oI6.png)
But i want to know how to program and save to local disk using octokit.net:
- save in “zip” format?
- or in unpacked format?

I try to use the code, but creates an empty archive "* .zip"

```
var latestAsset = await client.Repository.Get("Ryozuki", "HelperBot");

//Download Release.zip here
var response = await client.Connection.Get<object>(new Uri(latestAsset.Url),
    new Dictionary<string, string>(), null);

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.HttpResponse.Body.ToString()); ;
File.WriteAllBytes("RyozukiHelperBot.zip", bytes);
```

Link repo - https://github.com/Ryozuki/HelperBot

Comment: What does `byte[]null=..` mean?

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes This is mistake. I do not know how it turned out.
I fixed the code